# How to detect static ip using win app in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ip-address

Please correct me if i am wrong. There are two types of IP -
One, the static(fixed) IP address we assign to the LAN card and second that we received from the service provider.

For ex. The IP address set for my machine is 192.168.1.10 while the IP address given by ISP is 218.64.xx.xx. (You can check this using http://www.ip2location.com/)

When I use ASP.net, i can get the IP address provided by ISP using -
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

The Problem:
Now, I am working in Windows Forms environment but unable to get the IP provided by ISP, though I am able to get the fixed IP.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks for sharing your time.

Comment: Why do you need that IP address in a winforms app?

Comment: This is called an external IP address, not a static IP.  It's usually dynamic.

Comment: @Timbo: I need it in product registration process. I need the ip from which the product is being activated. This ip is sent over to a web service.

Comment: The client of the registration is sending its "own" public IP address in a data packet? The server should be able to get that address from the incoming connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to get the external IP address of your router.

You need to send an HTTP request to a third-party service which will reply with the IP address.

You can do that using the `WebClient` class.

For example:

```
///<summary>Gets the computer's external IP address from the internet.</summary>
static IPAddress GetExternalAddress() {
    //<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: 129.98.193.226</body></html>
    var html = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.com/");

    var ipStart = html.IndexOf(": ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 2;
    return IPAddress.Parse(html.Substring(ipStart, html.IndexOf("</", ipStart, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) - ipStart));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The terminology is wrong; your machine has a *private* IP and a *public* IP (not "static" and "dynamic").

To get the public IP, you need to bounce off a public server, e.g., whatismyip.org or your own server.

Comment: His machine does not have a public IP, his router does ;)

Answer (score 1):

i found manu methods one of them is a html request to     http://whatismyip.com

```
public static IPAddress GetExternalIp()
            {
                string whatIsMyIp = "http://whatismyip.com";
                string getIpRegex = @"(?<=<TITLE>.*)\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*(?=</TITLE>)";
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
                string requestHtml = "";
                try
                {
                    requestHtml = utf8.GetString(wc.DownloadData(whatIsMyIp));
                }
                catch (WebException we)
                {
                    // do something with exception
                    Console.Write(we.ToString());
                }
                Regex r = new Regex(getIpRegex);
                Match m = r.Match(requestHtml);
                IPAddress externalIp = null;
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    externalIp = IPAddress.Parse(m.Value);
                }
                return externalIp;
            }
```

or use

```
IPHostEntry IPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
Console.Write(IPHost.AddressList[0].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in the System.Net namespace:

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())
```

Comment: No, you can't.  He wants the _external_ IP.

Answer (score 0):

try with this (using System.Net):

```
IPHostEntry he = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName());
var s = he.AddressList[0].ToString(); // returns IP address
```