# Get A Computer's Dynamic Public IP Address

Tags: c#, winforms, dns, ip

I've managed to get my static IP Address and some other mac addresses.

Using this code :

```
IPAddress[] addr = Dns.GetHostEntry( Dns.GetHostName() ).AddressList;
string dynamicip = addr[addr.Length - 3].ToString();
```

Any idea how to get the dynamic public address like the one on the site whatismyip.com?

Comment: Take a look at this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363/get-external-ip-address-over-remoting-in-c)

Comment: You cannot do it without a 3rd party -- you need some site outside your network that can respond with the IP it saw your traffic from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is probably the question that you're asking: [How to get the IP address of the server on which my C# application is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

whatismyip.com has an api (sort of) setup for this purpose [here](http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp). you can use

```
public static IPAddress GetExternalIP()
{
        string url = "http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        string response = utf8.GetString(webClient .DownloadData(whatIsMyIp));
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(response);
        return ip;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for IP Address you can use HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

for windows form check [How to detect static ip using win app in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899436/how-to-detect-static-ip-using-win-app-in-c)

brgds

Comment: nop, this is not the solution for windows form. that is for asp. I added a stack post explaining for winforms

Comment: @ sebastian_h, suppose if I want a product registration by detecting the ipaddress of the windows application's computer, how can I achieve if the computer is behind a router with static ip address ?